# If I lose the privilege of voting up, will the votes I already cast be removed?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, privileges

What if people vote down my question(s)/answer(s) and then I lose some rep points (**below the level required to vote up**), and the privilege of voting up goes down the toilet with it (until I regain the reputation points needed). Do the up-votes I already gave other Q&As disappear, **lowering back that user's reputation in the process** (I mean the author of the question/answer I voted up)? I think the answer is a bit self-evident, but *I can't be sure*.

Comment: No. A downvote chain reaction does not happen.

Comment: Would be fun though, especially since suspensions reduce reputation to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do the up-votes I already gave other Q&As disappear, lowering back that user's reputation in the process […]?

No. The votes you once cast can not be removed like that. The only exception, where votes "magically" disappear, is when you use your votes in a non-constructive way, e.g. by only voting for one user, or aggressively downvoting specific users.

When you lose a privilege, *nothing* retroactive is done. You just don't have the privilege anymore, simple as that. Similarly, when you lose the editing privilege, all your edits stay.